# Image sprites for navigation

Tags: css, navigation, sprite

I am trying to use this image for the navigation but this is my first time working with sprites and I can't seem to get it to work. The main image shows up but the hover states do not work, and the cursor does not indicate that they are even links. I know there are other ways to do this without using an image sprite, but for the sake of troubleshooting, just pretend they don't exist.

I am a noob when it comes to html and css which doesn't help any either. If somebody can please tell me how stupid I am I would greatly appreciate it!

(It won't let me post the image)

```
<nav>
    <ul id="main-navigation">
        <li id="home"><a href="http://www.andrewblike.com/home.shtml" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li id="videos"><a href="http://www.andrewblike.com/video.shtml" title="Videos">Videos</a></li>
        <li id="recentWork"><a href="http://www.vimeo.com/andrewblike" title="Recent Work">Recent Work</a></li>
        <li id="bio"><a href="http://www.andrewblike.com/bio.shtml" title="Film Maker's Bio">Bio</a></li>
        <li id="castingCall"><a href="http://www.andrewblike.com/casting.shtml" title="Casting Call">Casting Call</a></li>
        <li id="contact"><a href="http://www.andrewblike.com/contact.shtml" title="Contact Me">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

/*CSS*/

```
nav {
width: 100%;
}

#main-navigation {
background: url('images/nav_sprite2.jpg') no-repeat;
width: 612px;
height: 44px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#main-navigation li, #mainNavigation a {
height: 45;
display: block;
}

#main-navigation li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
display: inline;
text-indent: -9999em;
}

 #home { width: 53px; }
 #videos { width: 64px; }
 #bio { width: 29px; }
 #recentWork { width: 127px; }
 #castingCall { width: 125px; }
 #contact { width: 116px; }

 #home a:hover { background:url('images/nav_sprite2.jpg') 0px -45px no-repeat; }
 #videos a:hover { background:url('images/nav_sprite2.jpg') -53px -45px no-repeat; }
 #bio a:hover { background:url('images/nav_sprite2.jpg') -157px -45px no-repeat; }
 #recentWork a:hover { background:url('images/nav_sprite2.jpg') -204px -45px no-repeat; }
 #castingCall a:hover { background:url('images/nav_sprite2.jpg') -351px -45px no-repeat; }
 #contact a:hover { background:url('images/nav_sprite2.jpg') -496px -45px no-repeat; }
```

/*End CSS*/

Comment: There's a good example of how to do this here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your CSS code:

- `#mainNavigation a` should be `#main-navigation a`
- `#main-navigation li` is assigned `display:inline` and later `display:block`. You need the latter in this case for the `A` elements to be as high as the `LI` elements..
- `height:45` should be `height:45px`
- I think you need to take this line out: `text-indent: -9999em;`
- It would be better to only use `background-position` in those `#id a:hover` rules and put the `background: url(...) no-repeat` in a rule for `#main-navigation a:hover`.

Comment: Agreed - but your code will work if you fix just the first of these (#mainNavigation a)...